# Ada: What does 'is type access' mean?

Tags: ada

I came across this piece of code from my assignment:

```
procedure Refs is
   type Node is
      record
         Content : Integer;
         Name    : Character;
      end record;

   type XNode is access Node;

   type NodeArray is array (Positive range 1 .. 5) of XNode;

[...]
```

And I cant seem to grok it (to the point that I could explain it to my grandmother) even after reading documentation, wiki etc.

Can someone explain in simple terms what that access keyword means ?

Comment: pointer to Node, in C terms.

Comment: @BrianDrummond just a pointer, or does it hold data, or do I have to supply it ?

Comment: It's a pointer. If it isn't `null`; the thing it points to holds data.

Comment: @BrianDrummond that makes sense, thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know nothing about Ada, but thankfully the answer is just 3 seconds of Googling away: `XNode` is an *access type* for `Node`. An *access type* is a type which grants access to dynamically allocated values of another type.

In other words, it is a pointer. But don't confuse this with the C concept of a pointer. Ada pointers are pointer-safe and memory-safe, you cannot, for example, add `1` to it and have it point to a different piece of memory, or have it point to some random address and claim "this memory is now a `Node`" (aka *type casting*).

It is more like an *object reference* in Java, ECMAScript, Python, or Ruby.

Comment: ... or indeed a reference in Algol-W,, Pascal etc.

Comment: … or any other sensible language. Ahem.

Comment: Did I just call ECMAScript and PHP sensible?